# How to implement `isEqual` method conveniently using Mirror in Swift 3

Tags: swift, foundation

like

```
class A :NSObject {
    let a :Int
    let b :UIColor
}
```

I don't want to implement `isEqual` by comparing all properties one by one. If that, When I add another property, I should modify `isEqual`'s implement again.

When using `Mirror` in swift, I could print all properties conveniently. How do I implement `isEqual` method conveniently by using `Mirror`.

Comment: Those colons... MY EYES!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't use runtime introspection other than for diagnostics, and certainly not to avoid small amounts of "boilerplate" code or to avoid updating existing code.

Below follows, however, some comments on the subject, but note that ***these should be considered hacks and should not be used in any kind of production code***. They can, however, show some example usage of runtime introspection in Swift.

#### Equatable `class`/`struct` "wrapper", using runtime introspection for property-by-property equality testing

You could implement an `Equatable`-container for holding values of equatable types, which can (different from `Equatable` itself) be casted to, which we will make use of to compare properties of say, a `class` or a `struct`.

```
/*  Heterogeneous protocol acts as castable Equatable container used for
    property-by-property equality testing in EquatableConstruct   */
protocol PseudoEquatableType {
    func isEqual(to other: PseudoEquatableType) -> Bool
}

extension PseudoEquatableType where Self : Equatable {
    func isEqual(to other: PseudoEquatableType) -> Bool {
        if let o = other as? Self { return self == o }
        return false
    }
}
```

with the `class`/`struct` equatable "wrapper" and its conformance to `Equatable` implemented (ab)using runtime introspection:

```
/*  EquatableConstruct and its conformance to Equatable  */
protocol EquatableConstruct : Equatable { }
func ==<T: EquatableConstruct>(lhs: T, rhs: T) -> Bool {

    let mirrorLhs = Mirror(reflecting: lhs)
    let mirrorRhs = Mirror(reflecting: rhs)

    guard let displayStyle = mirrorLhs.displayStyle,
        (displayStyle == .struct || displayStyle == .class) else {

            print("Invalid use: type is not a construct.")
            return false
    }

    let childrenLhs = mirrorLhs.children.filter { $0.label != nil }
    let childrenRhs = mirrorRhs.children.filter { $0.label != nil }

    guard childrenLhs.count == childrenRhs.count else { return false }

    guard !childrenLhs.contains(where: { !($0.value is PseudoEquatableType) }) else {
        print("Invalid use: not all members have types that conforms to PseudoEquatableType.")
        return false
    }

    return zip(
        childrenLhs.flatMap { $0.value as? PseudoEquatableType },
        childrenRhs.flatMap { $0.value as? PseudoEquatableType })
        .reduce(true) { $0 && $1.0.isEqual(to: $1.1) }
}
```

---

#### Example usage

We setup some non-native types to use in the example:

```
struct MyStruct {
    var myInt: Int = 0
    var myString: String = ""
}

class MyClass {
    var myInt: Int
    var myString: String
    var myStruct: MyStruct
    var myColor: UIColor

    init(myInt: Int, myString: String,
         myStruct: MyStruct, myColor: UIColor) {
        self.myInt = myInt
        self.myString = myString
        self.myStruct = myStruct
        self.myColor = myColor
    }
}
```

For some given type, e.g. `MyClass`, the `EquatableConstruct` "equatable wrapper" may be used only if all types of different properties in the type itself (here, in `MyClass`) themselves conform to `PseudoEquatableType`:

```
/* Extend (some/all) fundamental (equatable) Swift types to PseudoEquatableType  */
extension Bool : PseudoEquatableType {}    
extension Int : PseudoEquatableType {}
// ... Int8, UInt8, ..., Double, Float, ... and so on

extension String : PseudoEquatableType {}
extension UIColor: PseudoEquatableType {}

/* As a MyStruct instance is contained in MyClass, extend MyStruct to PseudoEquatableType
 to add the type to allowed property types in EquatableConstruct    */
extension MyStruct : PseudoEquatableType {}

/* Conformance to EquatableConstruct implies conformance to Equatable */
extension MyStruct : EquatableConstruct {}
extension MyClass : EquatableConstruct {}
```

Testing the automatic `Equatable` conformance of `MyStruct` and `MyClass`, given by their conformance to `EquatableConstruct`:

```
/* Example */
var aa = MyStruct()
var bb = MyStruct()

aa == bb            // true
aa.myInt = 1
aa == bb            // false

var a = MyClass(myInt: 10, myString: "foo",
                myStruct: aa, myColor: UIColor(white: 1.0, alpha: 1.0))
var b = MyClass(myInt: 10, myString: "foo",
                myStruct: aa, myColor: UIColor(white: 1.0, alpha: 1.0))

a == b              // true
a.myInt = 2
a == b              // false
b.myInt = 2
b.myString = "Foo"
a.myString = "Foo"
a == b              // true
a.myStruct.myInt = 2
a == b              // false
a.myStruct.myInt = 1
a == b              // true
a.myColor = UIColor(white: 0.5, alpha: 1.0)
a == b              // false
```

Comment: "these should be considered hacks and should not be used in any kind of production code" why?

Comment: @ScottyBlades I posted this more than four years now, but if I recall: the fact that it uses runtime introspection to define a (pseudo-)equatable contract based on mirror (that, IIRC, back then was mainly intended to be used in playgrounds and in debug; I'm now following the state of Swift these days) in a langauge that takes pride to be static, as opposed to its extremely dynamic sibling Obj-C. I think my first sentence of this answer already gives you my rationale for this, though: "You shouldn't use runtime introspection other than for diagnostics, [...]".

Comment: Thank you.  I guess I figure the usual explicit equality checks aren't any more static than using mirror.  Struct/Class property names are statically set, mirror just dynamically identifies them...But then again, there would be no static check or warning if a developer has no properties in the conforming struct or class...